# Rails - how do I refresh an item in a cached partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am having this scenario (main view template):

```
<% if @cars.count(:all) > 0 %>
  <% presenter.collection.each_pair do |date, collection| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
    </tr>
    <%= render partial: 'car_row_content', collection: collection, as: :car, cached: Proc.new{|car| [cache_prefix, acl_fingerprint, car.record] } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And here's how to the partial `car_row_content` looks like:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <%= car.something1 %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= car.something2 %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= car.something3 %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

In this partial, the attributes `something1` and `something2` stay the same all the time, but the attribute `something3` changes a lot (couple times a day).

What's happening here - when one of our admin changes the attribute `something3`, it's usually not "refreshed" immediately the main view template and we are seeing there the "old" value. How do I force Rails cache to immediately refresh when a change has happened?

Answer (score -1):

Use a cache key, when you update anything, cache key will be updated and your data will be updated.